# Rearragning matrix equation to find a matrix with multiple occurences

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given the equation:

> $T+TD+TR=Y$

I need to solve this for $T.$ I have dealt with more basic matrix equations and using the inverse to re-arrange formulas, but since there is an addition of the matrix $T,$ what is the first step I should take to solve this?

$T, D, R$ and I are $3\times 3$ matrices.

Comment: What kind of matrices are $D$, $R$, and $Y$?

Comment: ah - sorry about that, probably an important detail, I'll edit the question. 3x3's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we can consider the matrix $T$ to be $TI$, so $T$ is right multiplying each of $I$, $D$ and $R$, you can use the distributivity of matrix multiplication over addition to obtain $$T + TD + TR = TI + TD + TR = Y \iff T(I + D + R) = Y$$ If $\;(I + D + R)\,$ is an invertible square matrix, then $T = Y(I + D + R)^{-1}$.

Comment: OK, I think I kind of understand that. So the first step is factorizing the equation... so the identity matrix is in that bracket because T*I equates to T, and that is the same as just adding T on?

Comment: Yes, $T = TI$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. So $(I + D + R)$ is (the identity matrix $I + D + R)$. It's like factoring $6 + 6x = 6\cdot 1 + x = 6(1 + x)$, using the fact that the "identity" for multiplication of reals is $1$, and in the case of matrices, we use the identity for matrices: I.